# Prove that $f(x,y) = 10x^2+ 10y^2 + 12xy + 2x + 6y + 1 \geq 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to prove that 
$f(x,y) = 10x^2+ 10y^2 + 12xy + 2x + 6y + 1$ has a global minimum at the point $(1/8, -3/8)$.

Since $f(1/8, -3/8) = 0$, that would be proving that $f(x,y) \geq 0$ $\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 $

I tried completing squares but wasn't successful. I always ended up with at least term varying in sign.

Is there an alternative to the method of completing squares in case like this?

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Why not calculate the global minimum using the derivatives instead of completing squares?

Comment: What's the textbook definition for a global minimum? (Hint: it should involve derivatives).

Comment: Using the derivatives I only get the information that $f$ has a _local_ minimum at the point (1/8, -3/8)$. They don't speak for global situations (at least without knowing the shape of the function).

Comment: When you get all the local minima, just compare them to get a global minimum.

Comment: But you could get it wrong like that. Maybe the function goes to negative infinity and doesn't have a _global_ minimum. Or the same thing can happen with maximums.

Answer (score 0):

Completing the square works:
$(x+3y+1)^2=x^2+9y^2+1+2x+6y+6xy$, hence 
$$f(x,y)= (x+3y+1)^2 + 9x^2+y^2+6xy=(x+3y+1)^2+(3x+y)^2.$$

Comment: Great! I didn't attempt with squares of _three_ terms. I guess I was limited there. Thanks a lot! So the method of completing squares should work for all examples of this kind, right?

Comment: In principle you can, but in practice it may be very difficult to recognize squares, since a sum of several squares (eventually with cancellations...) can become very complicated.